# Defining unit tests in abstract generic test classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, generics, abstract-class

Is it possible to have a **generic abstract** base test class for unit tests in Visual Studio 2008?

If the base abstract test class is **not generic**, all its base methods marked with `[TestMethod]` are properly inherited in derived classes and executed in Visual Studio. If the base class is **generic**, then Visual Studio doesn't execute those methods in derived classes.

Imagine you have a bunch of parser classes implementing this interface (simplified):

```
// parses the input stream into an 
// instance of T
interface IParser<T> 
{
    IParserResult<T> Parse(byte[] input);
}
```

And imagine you have a bunch of parsers which can parse a certain stream:

```
class HeaderParser : IParser<T> { ... }
class SomeOtherParser : IParser<T> { ... }
... many more ...
```

To test the functionality of each parser, common testing pattern might be extracted into an abstract class like this:

```
[TestClass]
abstract class ParserTest<T>
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestParser()
    {
       // 1. init parser
       var parser = new T();

       // 2. get data
       var input = GetInputData();

       // 3. parse
       var result = parser.Parse(input);

       // 4. make common assertions
       Assert.AreEqual(ParserResultType.Success, result.Type);
       Assert.AreEqual(input.Length, result.NextDataOffset);

       // 5. specific validation
       Validate(result.Value);
    }

    protected abstract byte[] GetInputData(); 

    protected abstract void Validate(T result); 
}
```

If this class is generic and abstract, then the `TestParser` method won't be executed as a unit test for derived classes.

Comment: I believe that the `[TestMethod]` needs to be applied on the overridden class as well for it to be "seen" as test method.

Comment: why do you want to do this? Others reading your code would just see a TestClass but no methods under test, which is kinda disturbing

Comment: @Lucero: but there is only a single test method, the one in the base class. It doesn't make sense, because `Test` method becomes a member of each derived class, and it doesn't lose its attribute. Additionally, if I remove generics, then it works as expected.

Comment: @stijn: abstract classes extract common reusable logic to avoid code duplication. Does this mean any derived class looks "disturbing" because you need to jump to the base class to see the logic? And having public methods in the base abstract class with protected abstract methods to be overriden by concrete implementations is a pretty common pattern, isn't it?

Comment: no. You shouldn't be generalizing what I said. I was specifically referring to unit tests, as is your question. My point is that SomeMethod() is under test but it has no [TestMethod] attribute.

Comment: @stijn: I try to keep my unit testing code as refactored as my actual code. Copy-pasting a method 10 times is a bad practice, regardless of its purpose. And adding a dummy test method in each derived class just to have it marked with a `[TestMethod]` attribute is a pretty smelly practice.

Comment: I agree with you about the refactoring and getting rid of duplcicate code, but I solve this the other way around: I'd make a static AssertIsTrueForDefaultValue<T>( Func<bool,T> f ){ T value = default(T); Assert.IsTrue( f( value ) ); } method and call that with a lambda argument in SomeMethod(). No duplication, no need for a base class, and SomeMethod still has the TestMethod attribute.

Comment: @stijn, @Lucero: I have updated my answer, I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I went for a different approach, similar to what @stijn suggested a while ago.

I removed the abstract base class completely, and created a helper class which gets called from actual parser tests. This is a much better solution, because it allows reusing the same method with different combination of parameters and validation methods in each derived class (while abstract class only had a single pair of CreateData/TestResults abstract methods).

```
public class ParserTestHelper
{
    public static void Test<T>(
         Func<IParser<T>> getParser,
         Func<byte[]> getInput,
         Action<T> checkResult)
    {
        // get parser
        var parser = getParser();

        // get input data
        var input = getInput();

        // parse
        var result = parser.Parse(input, 0);

        // common assertions
        Assert.AreEqual(ParserResultType.Success, result.ResultType);
        Assert.AreEqual(input.Length, result.NextDataOffset);

        // validate results
        checkResult(result.ParsedValue);
    }
}
```

And derived classes can now simply call the method inside actual Test methods:

```
[TestClass]
public class HeaderParserTest
{
     [TestMethod]
     public void TestHeader() 
     {
         ParserTestHelper.Test(
            () => new HeaderParser(),
            () => /* generate data */,
            () => /* validate results */);
     }
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with stijns comments on your question. I prefer all testing of an object is gathered in one fixture. Further, if you keep tests in an abstract class, it means that your are testing the same functionality over and over again. This is at best redundant repeating; at worst confusing to the reader. 
Finally , your needs indicate that your tested objects may be in need of a common abstract base class. If this is the case, you should test the base class separately, and test each of the derived classes without testing the functionality of the base class.

That being said, I have sometimes used base classes for setup and teardown to avoid doing the same thing again and again. The most common situation for me is when I have to initiate licenses before being able to use a SDK. I have still not entirely conviced myself that this is a pretty way to go DRY though.

Comment: I've updated my question. My tested classes all share the same generic interface (not a base class), but implementation varies. Since the interface is the same, test class can test each instance in the same way, passing only different parameters.

Comment: @Groo: Okay, but I don't see what good it makes that to hide the test in a base class, when both the setup and the assertion is done in the real test class anyway. In my eyes the only result is confusion (by hiding tests). But I may be wrong. Maybe I have overlooked some benefits of this pattern.

Comment: That's right, actual testing logic resides in derived classes, but test setup and validation of results is exactly the same in every test (1. create parser, 2. get test stream, 3. execute, 4. verify). I repeated the same pattern several times myself before I decided to extract it to a base class, and was confused that the test doesn't get called. On the other hand, if the base test class is **not generic**, then it works fine (each derived class gets its inherited test method).

Comment: As I see it, the business part of setup is done in the derived classes with the local implementations of GetInputData(). How many lines do you actually save with this pattern? Not enough to pay for the resulting pains IMHO. Sorry, but I cannot help with the generic issue.